# Returning a list or tuple in Python Sphinx

Tags: python, return, python-sphinx

I am documenting with sphinx and i have functions that return lists/tuples etc.

So for parameters the following links to the python documentation:

```
:param list myVar:
```

But for the return value neither of the following work:

```
:rtype: list
:rtype: :class:`list`
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Python documentation, the function named `list` is linked to when referring to lists. So, try:

```
:rtype: :func:`list`
```